# Prove that both $\sum|f_n|$ and $\sum f_n$ converge uniformly on X.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Please, check item "a" and help me to find a solution for item "b". Thanks!

Question:

a) Given a sequence of functions $f_nX \rightarrow \mathbb R$, suppose there exists $c \in \mathbb R$ such that $\sqrt[n]{|f_n(x)|} \le c<1$, for every $x \in X$ and $n$ greater then a certain $n_0$. Prove that both $\sum|f_n|$ and $\sum f_n$ converge uniformly on X.

Solution: $\sqrt[n]{|f_n(x)|} \le c<1 \Rightarrow |f_n|\le c^n<1$, where $\sum c^n$ is convergent. Then the Test of Weirstrass says that both $\sum|f_n|$ and $\sum f_n$ uniformly converge on X.

b) Suppose that instead of $\sqrt[n]{|f_n(x)|} \le c<1$ we have $\left|\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}\right| \le c<1$, for every $x \in X$, $n$ greater than a certain $n_0$, with $f_n(x) \neq 0$, for every $n \in \mathbb N$, $x \in X$. Show that the same conclusion holds.

Solution: Now I see a problem.$\left|\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}\right| \le 1$ implies $\sum f_n$ converges absolutely, i.e, $\sum|f_n|$ is convergent. Then $\sum|f_n|c$ also converges, because $\sum| f_n|c < \sum |f_n|$. Then we have $\left|\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}\right| \le c \Rightarrow \frac{|f_{n+1}|}{|f_n|} \le c \Rightarrow |f_{n+1}| \le |f_n|c$, with $\sum|f_n|c$ convergent. But $|f_n|$ is not a constant, so the Test of Weirstrass doesn't apply.

Comment: I hastily incorrectly answered this question, but there is a flaw in the problem statement. See my corrected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same conclusion does not hold in part (b) unless you add additional conditions. Take, for example, $X=(0,1)$ and $f_n(x) = 2^{-n}/x$. Then $f_{n+1}/f_n = 1/2$ and $f_n \to 0$, but it does not converge uniformly.

But otherwise if $|f_0|$ is bounded, then you are very, very close. Show with induction that $|f_n| \leq c^n |f_0| \leq M c^n$ where $M$ is the bound on $f_0$. Then use the Weierstrass M-test.